# why my submit button not show page isn't available after clicking

Tags: javascript, html, button, submit

Hi I have run this code and its working well but when i click on submit button it doesn't show page isn't available . how do I get page isn't available after clicking submit button

<

```
html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content ="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <title> practice</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <h1><b>Welcome to the your page.</b></h1>
            <form  action="/" name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
             
             
             <div id="name">
            What is your name?:
            <input  type="text" name="fname"  placeholder="Required" required> 
            <span class ="formerror"></span>
            </div> 
            <input type="button" name="mybutton" value="Submit" >
        strong text
        </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what did you really mean by "get page isn't available". But to make the form submit correctly you have to replace

```
<input type="button" name="mybutton" value="Submit" >
```

with this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

The input type should be `submit`. Not `button`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace

```
<form  action="/" name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

to

```
<form  action="#" name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

Hope it works:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<input type="submit" name="mybutton" value="Submit" >
```